# focus EditText ONLY on Click or Tap and NOT on scroll or swipe over it in Android

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext, click

I have an `EditText`

Rightnow when a user SWIPE or SCROLL or TAP or CLICK over it, it gets focus.

I want it to receive focus ONLY on TAP or CLICK on it. And not on SWIPE or SCROLL on it.

How can i achieve that?

I Googled it a lot and was only able to find answers about focusing and unfocusing by click on some other element / view.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in your parent layout

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```